# I can't get image to display

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jpanel

I have a chat client program I am working on and currently I can get the text pane, text input on the left. I can add buttons and change the background color to the right but I can not get an image to display on the right. There is more than one way to skin a cat on this from what I've read but I'm trying to stick with the setup I currently have so I don't have to rewrite everything. I understand the basics of Java (OOP) and how it works. I'm just lost as to how to format image icon and get this image to display. Here is the code: I am compiling with IntelliJ.

```
package edu.lmu.cs.networking;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChatClient {
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatter");
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;

    public ChatClient() {
        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        // frame.setSize(500, 500);
        // frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "South");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "West");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        button = new JButton("Button");
        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("x.gif"));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                out.println(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private String getServerAddress() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
                "Welcome to the Chatter", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    private String getName() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Choose a screen name:", "Screen name selection",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    private void run() throws IOException {
        // Make connection and initialize streams
        String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 5910);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                textField.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
-Brandon

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: For example, what is this `CreateImageIcon` class that you appear to be creating inside of your JLabel? Why not call the actual ImageIcon constructor?

Comment: I posted the whole code. It compiles just fine. Just no image. I was trying something different with the CreateImageIcon I edited that out.

Comment: Your question is the same as the hundreds of others like it -- you're not looking correctly for the image, the path to the image file is relative to the user's directory, and you're not taking account of that. But regardless, you should use Resources as Keqiang recommends.

Comment: But thank you for now posting code that makes more sense.

Comment: Another problem is that you will want to correct this code so that it obeys Swing threading rules. In your run method, which runs in a background thread, you're making mutation changes to Swing components, to the textField and the messageArea. These changes should only be made on the Swing event thread, and so you'll need to take care to place those lines in a Runnable and to queue it onto the Swing event thread from within your background thread. This has nothing to do with your image error, but with your future threading error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is in your projects root directory,then you can access it the directly,similar to what you have done.
If it is inside some folder(say resources folder) in your project structure you need to use `getClass().getResource("/resources/x.gif")`.

You can also create a scaled version of the image,specifying the height and width.It can be done using the sample code below:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("x.gif");
  Image img = icon.getImage();
  Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(30, 20,
            java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
  label = new JLabel(icon);
```

Comment: I remarked out my code, copy and pasted this and still nothing. The image is in the folder. I have tested and run several basic image programs with success. It's just when I try to add to this socket code it won't display. Same exact image has worked in simpler programs. I also posted the full project code if you wish to try and complie it yourself

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your project structure?Just to check where exactly the image is and the java file accessing the image.

Comment: I compiled and executed your class and it works fine,displays a gif image which i placed in the root folder.Please share your folder structure and that might help to figure out the issue.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at the directory structure and I noticed a lot of extra stuff that didn't belong there because of dozens of different things I have tried. The picture was in the root directory of the project just like all the other image programs I have tested. I copied my code and trashed the whole project and started a fresh new one. Your code worked perfectly this time. I have been programing since the apple IIgs and C on PC and things like this I will never understand. I've been stuck on this for 5 days now. Thank you everyone for your advice and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your code as below and it will work. Just tested it on my own computer and it worked.

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.gif"));

    label = new JLabel(icon);
```

It seems your problem is that you didn't actually loaded the image in. Remember to use a ClassLoader to load the resource files.

You should place 'x.gif' under your project directory or your resource folder(preferred) in order to make this work.

For more details about loading resources, take a look at [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/).